# Calling functions when using parallel programming

Tags: c++, c, function, mpi

I just have a fairly simple question about using MPI in a C++ program. Indeed, let's take this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cblas.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

#include <mpi.h>

void multiply(double* x,double* y,int tai,double dot){
    for(int i=0; i<tai;i=i+1){
        dot=dot+x[i]*y[i];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const int n=32;
    int rank;
    int size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int tai=n/size;
    double* x=new double[tai];
    double* y=new double[tai];
    srand(time(0)+rank);

    for(int i=0;i<tai;i=i+1){
        x[i]=(double)rand()/RAND_MAX*10;
        y[i]=(double)rand()/RAND_MAX*10;
    }
    double dot=0;
    multiply(x,y,tai,dot);
    double ddot;
    MPI_Reduce(&dot, &ddot, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if(rank==0){
        cout<<"product:"<<ddot<<endl;
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Then, I call my function "multiply" in my program to multiply two vectors but unfortunately it returns the initial value of "dot" (which is basically 0).

I just would like to know if there is anything special about calling a function when we are doing parallel programming.

PS: I know the whole program is working as it gives me good results when I directly multiply my 2 vectors in the "main" function

Comment: `multiply` doesn't return anything (its return type is `void` and it doesn't seem to have output parameters). Can you show a [mcve] so that we can see how you're calling it?

Comment: Consistent indentation makes code much easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I just edited my question in order to show a simple example of how I use it.

Comment: Please, please, please, use proper indenting.

Comment: This is not written in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial value of `dot` is not changing is because it is passed by value. A copy of `dot` is made when passed to `multiply` and that is the version that is modified. If you want `multiply` to modify the `dot` variable, and keep the changes outside the `multiply` function, pass `dot` by reference.

```
void multiply(double* x, double* y, int tai, double& dot);
```

The fact that you are using MPI has no effect on this behavior.

Comment: Indeed, it is working now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the provided code having issues, the answer to your question is no, each processing element will go through the function as it's called, but maybe you don't want each processing element to do the whole dot product and you'd be better off using a scatterv and gatherv to split the program; or maybe each processing element has its own unique vectors that get reduced or added later and you're fine. Be sure to use MPI types.